# Avoiding/minimising looped SQL queries in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, pdo

Assume I have an $array of elements (and their associated sub-elements), following roughly this format:

```
[0] => Array (
   [valA] => PA0000001
   [valB] => qwerty
   [valC] => asdfgh
   [valD] => zxcvbn
   [valE] => poiuyt
   [valF] => lkjhgf
)
```

And so on, with a potentially very large number of elements (and sub-elements). I would like to use this array to create and update records in my SQL Server database. But before I let all of those records loose, I would like to check them against a set of predetermined rules. For example:

> valA must exist in the column alphID on table Alpha
>
> valB must exist in the column bravId on table Bravo
>
> valD must exist in the column deltID on table Delta
>
> valF must exist in the column foxID on table Foxtrot

The obvious solution is to loop through each element of the array, and run something like the following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT (SELECT alphID FROM Alpha WHERE alphID = :alphID) AS AlphaExists, 
       (SELECT bravID FROM Bravo WHERE bravID = :bravID) AS BravoExists,
       (SELECT deltID FROM Delta WHERE deltID = :deltID) AS DeltaExists,
       (SELECT foxID FROM Foxtrot WHERE foxID = :foxID) AS FoxtrotExists";
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
//Bind PDO values with appropriate array values here
$rslt = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return($rslt);
```

And then use that to make sure things are alright.

However, that does not scale terribly well - the overhead of connecting to the database, running a query, returning the results and assigning them is tiny for one query, but when there are multiple thousands of them it quickly becomes unworkable.

Is there a better, more efficient method of performing these lookups and returning something that will tell me, for each of the elements, which rules have been met/not met?

Comment: Any reason for not using foreign key constraint? If a query violates the foreign key constraint the database will spout error.

Comment: @frz3993 I'm assuming you mean performing an insert/update and relying on the foreign key constraint there? The spec calls for the user to be able to see all of the anticipated problems with their data before they commit it. The database would just give me whatever error it runs into first and stop, unless I miss my guess, and these aren't technical people, besides. Giving them an SQL Server error message isn't ideal. Further, some of the rules aren't 'does this exist' (E.g. display which existing records will change vs be added), which makes using FKs problematic.